# Why are there two different git commits for the same tag?

Tags: git

I'm trying to determine the commit SHA associated with a particular tag.  When I execute `show-ref`, I get the following output

```
$ git show-ref my_tag
6a390ca7bca7b52b2009069138873fdbc7922c1d refs/tags/my_tag
```

When I execute `rev-list` I get this output

```
$ git rev-list -n 1 my_tag
b6dcf8fa20296d146e9501ab9d25784879adeac8
```

The commit SHA's are different, but I don't understand why.  It looks like `b6dcf8`, generated by `rev-list`, is the correct one.  If I try and checkout the first commit with `git checkout 6a390c` and then look at the log, I'm not actually on `6a390c`; `b6dcf8` is displayed.

Can anyone explain why there might be a disconnect?  Why am I redirected to `b6dcf8` when I try and checkout `6a390ca`.

**Update**

I also noticed that when I execute `git show my_tag`, I get output that looks like this

```
tag my_tag
Tagger: Me <me@me.com>
Date:   Mon Apr 4 14:43:46 2016 -0400

Tagging Release my_tag

tag my_tag_Build_1
Tagger: Me <me@me.com>
Date:   Thu Mar 31 10:46:18 2016 -0400

Tagging my_tag_Build_1

commit b6dcf8fa20296d146e9501ab9d25784879adeac8
Author: Me <me@me.com>
Date:   Wed Mar 30 18:12:10 2016 -0400

Remove secret_key_base values from secrets.yml
```

It's picking up two tags `my_tag` and `my_tag_Build_1`.  However, if I run `git tag`, the list of tags only has

```
my_tag
```

If I run `git show my_tag_Build_1`, I get

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'my_tag_Build_1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
```

It seems like git is confused.  Maybe the `my_tag_Build_1` tag existed at some point, but it doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Comment: We can't see your repo, but presumably my_tag is an annotated tag, and 6a390c is the tag object.

Comment: Did you mean `git rev-list -n 1 my_tag`?

Comment: Yes, thanks for spotting that.  I've updated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll add one more answer, even though [Marcelo Ávila de Oliveira's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39755108/1256452) is correct, because I want to draw the graph bits. :-)

Normally I like to draw commit graphs like this, at least for StackOverflow:

```
...--A--B--C     <-- foobranch
         \
          D--E   <-- barbranch
```

Here the two *tip* (rightmost) commits on the two branches, `C` and `E`, each have a branch name pointing to them.  That is, `refs/heads/foobranch` contains the ID of commit `C`, and `refs/heads/barbranch` contains the ID of commit `E`.

#### Lightweight tags

Lightweight tags work exactly like branch names.  If we add the tag `bartag` to point to commit `E`, we get:

```
...--A--B--C     <-- foobranch
         \
          D--E   <-- barbranch, tag: bartag
```

where `refs/heads/bartag` (an actual file in `.git` unless it has become "packed" and is now stored in the file `.git/packed-refs` instead) also stores the ID of commit `E`.  There are three differences between a lightweight tag and a branch:

1. The lightweight tag's full name starts with `refs/tags/` instead of `refs/heads/`.
2. The lightweight tag should never change to point to another commit (this is only semi-enforced by Git, and poorly so in versions prior to 1.8.something, but branch names do normally change which commit they point to, vs tags, which don't).
3. Git enforces a rule that branch names shall only point to commit objects.  Normally tag names *also* only point to commit objects, but it's possible to make one that points to a tree or blob.  There's one more object type—the *annotated tag* object—but that makes the tag different!  Hold on to that thought, and let's finish this part up.

A *lightweight tag*, then, is simply a reference whose full name is spelled `refs/tags/...`.  This external reference exists somewhere—often as a separate file like `.git/refs/tags/bartag`—and it points to a Git object in the repository (`.git/objects/...`, possibly packed into a pack-file).  When it points to a commit, which is the normal case, this gets us into the commit DAG: the tag locates the commit, which can get us a work-tree, and also lets us explore earlier (ancestor) commits by following the "parent" ID, going from commit `E` back to `D`.

#### Annotated tags

An annotated tag uses almost the same picture, except now, instead of the lightweight tag `bartag` pointing *directly* to a commit, now Git stores an *annotated tag* object into the repository.  This annotated tag object has its own data (date, tagger, message, optional digital signature, and whatever else you like), and also stores one hash ID.  The hash ID is the target (or `object`, as Git spells it) for the tag.

I don't have a preferred style for drawing these here, so I'll just make something up:

```
...--A--B--C     <-- foobranch
         \
          D--E   <-- barbranch
             ^
             :
             t   <-- tag: annotag
```

Here, Git has stored a new *annotated tag* object `t` in the repository, and now we have the external reference `refs/tags/annotag` pointing to `t`.  Meanwhile it's the tag object `t` that points to commit `E`.

This means there are two hash IDs involved with tag `annotag`: the ID of the annotated tag object, and the ID of commit `E`.  Again, the *reference* points to the *annotated tag object*, and the object points to the next thing—in this case, to commit `E`.

As with lightweight tags, though, annotated tag objects can point to other object types than commits.  A lightweight tag cannot point to an annotated tag object, but that's only because, when the reference points to an annotated object, we no longer *call* it a "lightweight" tag, we now call it an "annotated" tag.  An annotated tag object, however, can point to another annotated tag object.  Let's do that and make `zomgtag` point to object `t`:

```
...--A--B--C     <-- foobranch
         \
          D--E   <-- barbranch
             ^
             :
             t   <-- tag: annotag
             ^
             :
             z   <-- tag: zomgtag
```

#### If you delete one of these...

Now let's try *deleting* tag `annotag`.  One interesting thing about Git is that deleting a *reference* **does not** actually delete the underlying object.  Underlying objects are normally left around until there is too much garbage cluttering up the repository, at which point Git runs `git gc --auto` for you.  The GC (Garbage Collector) finds the unreferenced objects and actually removes them.  This GC is thus a sort of Grim Reaper, or perhaps Grim Collector, that recycles the dead objects back into usable disk space.

This is true for branch name references, for instance: deleting a branch name simply *abandons* the branch-tip commit, rather than actually deleting it.  Moreover, if there's some *other* way to reach that commit, the commit itself won't go away, even when the Grim Collector comes by.  If there's still some linkage, GC leaves the object in place.  For normal (non-deleted) branches, when you rebase (which copies commit chains to new chains), the original commit-chain tip IDs are stored in the branch's *reflog*, which keeps the entire chain reachable until the reflog entries expire.  (This means you can go back and recover rebased commits for at least 30 days by default, since 30 and 90 days are the default reflog expiration times.)

But these same rules apply to annotated tag objects!  So if we delete `annotag` while leaving in `zomgtag`, the picture is now:

```
...--A--B--C     <-- foobranch
         \
          D--E   <-- barbranch
             ^
             :
             t
             ^
             :
             z   <-- tag: zomgtag
```

There is no longer a *name* for tag object `t`, but it is *reachable* through `z`, which we reach through `refs/tags/zomgtag`, so `t` sticks around in the repository forever.  (Well, unless `zomgtag` is *also* deleted, so that `t` becomes unreferenced.)

Now there are *two* Git objects involved in `zomgtag`: starting from the external reference, we find the annotated tag object `z`.  From this we find the annotated tag object `t`, and from `t` we find commit `E`.

Git has a special syntax described in [the `gitrevisions` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) for "peeling" a tag: `zomgtag^{}`.  The description says:

> A suffix `^` followed by an empty brace pair means the object could be a tag, and dereference the tag recursively until a non-tag object is found.

If we make more annotated tags, we can have `refs/tags/wacky` point to a tag object that points to a second tag object that points to yet another tag object, that eventually, after following many tags, points to `z` which points to `t` which points to `E`.  The notation `wacky^{}` means "find the non-tag-object" (in this case, a commit, though as always, the endpoint can also be a tree or blob).

Comment: You sir are a true gentleman.  Thank for a well written answer!  I learned alot.

Answer (score 4):

You execute "git show my_tag" and see two tags because the my_tag tag was created using my_tag_Build_1 tag as parameter, like in the following command:

```
git tag -m "Tagging Release my_tag" -a my_tag my_tag_Build_1
```

On the other hand, I can't not explain why my_tag_Build_1 is not shown in the "git tag" command. This is really weird.

Comment: That makes sense.   I bet the `my_tag_Build_1` was deleted after the new `my_tag` was created.  Git must be keeping some info around for `my_tag_Build_1` for use in cases like this.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The intermediate tag is not showing up because it was deleted, so that its only *external* name is the one that does show up.

Answer (score 2):

Your tag is probably a packed tag, meaning a bunch of references have been put into one file for transfer efficiency. From the [`gitrepository-layout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout) docs:

```
packed-refs
    records the same information as refs/heads/, refs/tags/, and friends record in
    a more efficient way. See git-pack-refs(1). This file is ignored if
    $GIT_COMMON_DIR is set and "$GIT_COMMON_DIR/packed-refs" will be used instead.
```

From [`git-pack-refs`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-refs):

> Traditionally, tips of branches and tags (collectively known as refs) were stored one file per ref in a (sub)directory under $GIT_DIR/refs directory. While many branch tips tend to be updated often, most tags and some branch tips are never updated. When a repository has hundreds or thousands of tags, this one-file-per-ref format both wastes storage and hurts performance.

Look at `.git/packed-refs` and you'll see something like this.

```
6a390ca7bca7b52b2009069138873fdbc7922c1d refs/tags/my_tag
^b6dcf8fa20296d146e9501ab9d25784879adeac8
```

Basically the tag is an object that points to the commit. You can get around this with `-d` to dereference the tag. You should see something like this:

```
git show-ref -d my_tag
6a390ca7bca7b52b2009069138873fdbc7922c1d refs/tags/my_tag
b6dcf8fa20296d146e9501ab9d25784879adeac8 refs/tags/my_tag^{}
```

Comment: This isn't quite right: *any* annotated tag involves two Git objects: the annotated tag, and the target of that annotated tag. It does not matter whether the reference itself is packed. In the case in question here, there are *three* objects, though, because the first annotated tag points to a second annotated tag.

Comment: @torek Yeah, packed refs are still new to me. I'm not sure how this interacts with annotation. I checked it out on [my own project](https://github.com/evalEmpire/perl5i) which doesn't use annotated tags (used tag `v2.8.0`) but has them packed.

Comment: @torek I tested this just now with an unpacked annotated tag, and a packed annotated tag. Both had the same result, one level of indirection. So the OP could be in either situation: annotated tag, or a packed tag (annotated or not). Either way, `git show-ref -d` is the thing. Or are you saying it's a tag pointing at a deleted annotated tag pointing at a commit? Whoa.

Comment: Yes, it's a two-level annotated tag (there's no real limit to how long a tag chain can go, although to make crazy-long ones you'd want to use `git mktag` in a loop, rather than using `git tag -a` and then deleting the external refs).