# How can I get the commit hash of the latest release from Github API

Tags: github-api

I would like to get the git commit hash of latest tagged release from Github in repo. Is it possible to get it with the GitHub API?

This would be helpful, if not only for the use case below, where I need to use the Git Commit hash (instead of the tag) to download the vscode server code.

This is the code where I try to grab the microsoft/vscode latest commit hash:
https://github.com/b01/faith-works-t-shirts/blob/main/.docker/download-vs-code-server.sh

Comment: I see this questions has been marked down and also voted for closing. However I believe that a reason should be provided. Such as off-topic, too specific, or something. Do we just close things without leaving comments as to why now? I can't learn or improve without proper feedback.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Using Github Rest v3

You would need to get the tag using [get latest release API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-the-latest-release):

```
GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/releases/latest
```

example: https://api.github.com/repos/mui-org/material-ui/releases/latest

And then get the tag sha using the get tag API:

```
GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/git/ref/tags/{tag_name}
```

example: https://api.github.com/repos/mui-org/material-ui/git/ref/tags/v4.11.3

If the `type` is `commit`, the tag sha point to a commit, otherwise you need to call :

```
GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/git/tags/{tag_sha}
```

and get the `object.sha`
https://api.github.com/repos/$repo/git/tags/$tag_sha
example using [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) and [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) :

```sh
repo=microsoft/vscode

tag=$(curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/$repo/releases/latest" | jq -r '.tag_name')
read type tag_sha < <(echo $(curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/$repo/git/ref/tags/$tag" | 
     jq -r '.object.type,.object.sha'))

if [ $type == "commit" ]; then
    echo "commit sha: $tag_sha"
else
    sha=$(curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/$repo/git/tags/$tag_sha" | jq '.object.sha')
    echo "commit sha: $sha"
fi
```

#### GraphQL v4

Using [Graphql API v4](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql), it's more straightforward :

```json
{
  repository(owner: "microsoft", name: "vscode") {
    latestRelease{
      tagCommit {
        oid
      }
    }
  }
}
```

example using [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) and [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) :

```sh
repo=material-ui
owner=mui-org
token=YOUR_TOKEN

curl -s -H "Authorization: token $token" \
     -H  "Content-Type:application/json" \
     -d '{ 
          "query": "{repository(owner:\"'"$owner"'\", name:\"'"$repo"'\"){latestRelease{tagCommit {oid}}}}"
      }' https://api.github.com/graphql | jq -r '.data.repository.latestRelease.tagCommit.oid'
```

Comment: These work, but in some case the sha you get back from the API may not match what you see in the UI or the GraphQL API, for example when I tried these on 04/11/2021T06:52 AM

    https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/vscode/releases/latest
    https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/vscode/git/ref/tags/1.55.1

From the API: `825765b57869b765fc7c15cd3ff8e7f8350ac1a0`  
  
From GitHub UI I saw: `08a217c4d27a02a5bcde898fd7981bda5b49391b`  

From the GraphQL API; I get back `08a217c4d27a02a5bcde898fd7981bda5b49391b`  
  
But I guess that is a different question for another time.

Comment: @b01 see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39757198/2614364) related to packed ref. Indeed, when I clone the visualcode repo and `git show-ref -d 1.55.1` it gives `825765b57869b765fc7c15cd3ff8e7f8350ac1a0 refs/tags/1.55.1` and `08a217c4d27a02a5bcde898fd7981bda5b49391b refs/tags/1.55.1^{}`

Comment: I was aware of a the difference in tag types, but never took the time learn what the difference was. Very important to know in this case.

Comment: In an Alpine Docker container, for the GraphQL version I had to replace the `read` command with this:

`tag_data=$(curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/${1}/git/ref/tags/${tag}" | jq -r '.object.type,.object.sha')

sha_type=${tag_data%$'\n'*}
sha=${tag_data##*$'\n'}`